# Returning another anonymous function in lambda expression java

Tags: java, lambda, comparator

Is it possible to return another function in a lambda expression in java? Say I have the following lambda expressions

```
addFive = (x) -> x+5;
addFiveIfPositive = (y) -> {
    if (y > 0) return addFive;
    else return y;
};
```

To give some context behind I'm asking this, I'm working with lambda expressions to define Comparators and for some comparators, I want to 'chain' comparators that I've already defined to not write the same code again, given some conditions like in the example above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
This is a more representative example of what I'm working with.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

class Random{
    Integer val;
    String str;

    Random(int val, String str){
      this.val = new Integer(val);
      this.str = str;
    }
}

public class Temp{

  static Comparator<Random> c1 = (r1, r2) -> (r1.val).compareTo((r2.val));
  static Comparator<Random> c2 = (r1, r2) -> {
    if ((r1.str).compareTo((r2.str)) == 0){
      return c1.apply(r1,r2);
    }
    return (r1.str).compareTo((r2.str));
  };

  public static void main(String args){
    Random rand1 = new Random(1, "Hello");
    Random rand2 = new Random(2, "Hello");
    System.out.println(c2.compare(rand1, rand2));
  }
}
```

Using .apply() gives me the error

```
Temp.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
      return c1.apply(r1,r2);
               ^
  symbol:   method apply(Random,Random)
  location: variable c1 of type Comparator<Random>
```

Comment: Tack `.apply(y)` onto the end of `return addFive`

Comment: The compiler gives the error that it cannot find the method apply() when I tried it.

Comment: That edit changes the question completely... a `Comparator` isn't a Function so it doesn't have an `apply` method; it has a `compare(Object, Object)` method instead, *that's* what you need to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the edit, all you are looking for is to make use of:

```
Comparator<Random> c1 = Comparator.comparing(Random::getVal);
Comparator<Random> c2 = Comparator.comparing(Random::getStr).thenComparing(c1);;
```

that is because you already have `Comparator`s supporting the use case of chaining with the `thenComparing` API. Do note that this is just a simplification of the following code:

```
Comparator<Random> c1 = (r1, r2) -> (r1.val).compareTo((r2.val));
Comparator<Random> c2 = (r1, r2) -> {
    if ((r1.str).compareTo((r2.str)) == 0){
        return c1.compare(r1,r2); //'compare' instead of 'apply'
    }
    return (r1.str).compareTo((r2.str));
};
```

---

Prior to the edit, you could have used a ternary operator to represent the condition such as:

```
IntFunction<Integer> addFive = x -> x + 5;
IntFunction<Integer> addFiveIfPositive = y -> y > 0 ? y + 5 : y;
```

Comment: @Tom_G_99 The edit in the answer corresponds to your actual use case.

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty much there already - you're just missing one thing; inside `addFiveIfPositive` you need to return the result of applying `addFive` rather than returning the function itself. It's trivially easy to do, all you need is to `return addFive.apply(y);` instead of `return addFive;`

See the snippet below:

```
import java.util.function.IntFunction;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(doStuff(5));
        System.out.println(doStuff(-1));
    }

    public static int doStuff(int val) {

        IntFunction<Integer> addFive = (x) -> x+5;
        IntFunction<Integer> addFiveIfPositive = (y) -> {
            if (y > 0) return addFive.apply(y);
            else return y;
        };

        return addFiveIfPositive.apply(val);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
10
-1
```